# DirectoryEntry Invoke("Members", null) is not retrieving all the members

Tags: c#, windows, active-directory, active-directory-group

I have an ActiveDirectory Group called "AuditUsers" and it has some members.

This is my code:

```
` DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(ADSPath);
    DirectorySearcher deSearch = new DirectorySearcher(LDAP://CN=AuditUsers,OU=WEB Groups,OU=Groups,DC=doamin,DC=com);
    deSearch.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))"; 
     object members = de.Invoke("Members", null);`
```

So this object member doesn't pull all the users who are actually their members. Only some members are showing up. Does anyone have any idea why some people are missing here even if they are part of this group? IS any key field is missing in AD for those who are missed?

I checked the missing member's AD and found their objectCategory has person, objectClass has user. userAccountControl is same for those members who are pulled and not pulled.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Invoking [`IADsGroup.Members`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nf-iads-iadsgroup-members) is just the harder way of enumerating `de.Properties["member"]`. Both just read the `member` attribute of the group.

But that is not the only way a user can be a member. I go into it in more detail in [an article I wrote](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/06/07/what-makes-a-member.html), but what I suspect is going on here is that the group is used as the primary group for many of your users. And that membership is done differently.

If that is the case, then the `primaryGroupId` attribute of the users will be set to the Relative Identifier (RID) of the group. The RID is the last set of numbers in the SID (which can also be retrieved from the `primaryGroupToken` attribute of the group). In the article I wrote about [finding all the members of a group](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/11/30/find-all-members-of-group.html#primary-groups), I included an example of how to find all the users that have the group as their primary group. On my site it was returning the DOMAIN\username, but I modified it here so it returns the `distinguishedName`, so you can add what you get from this to what you get from the `member` attribute.

```cs
public static IEnumerable<string> GetPrimaryGroupMemberList(DirectoryEntry group) {
    group.RefreshCache(new[] { "distinguishedName", "primaryGroupToken" });

    var groupDn = (string) group.Properties["distinguishedName"].Value;
    var ds = new DirectorySearcher(
        new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://{groupDn.Substring(groupDn.IndexOf("DC=", StringComparison.Ordinal))}"),
        $"(&(objectClass=user)(primaryGroupId={group.Properties["primaryGroupToken"].Value}))",
        new [] { "distinguishedName" })
    {
        PageSize = 1000
    };

    using (var primaryMembers = ds.FindAll()) {
        foreach (SearchResult primaryMember in primaryMembers) {
            yield return (string) primaryMember.Properties["distinguishedName"][0];
        }
    }
}
```